# Prestashop - searching products show count of results but dont show products list

Tags: prestashop-1.6

i have problem with searching products. When i type something to search input i get count of results but dont products list.

example: http://www.knizny-fond.sk/sk/vyhledavani?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query=egypt&submit_search=

Can you help me pls?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you modified the search controller or search.tpl? That could be the problem.

If not, you can regenerate the Search Index.

Preferences -> Search -> and click on "Rebuild the complete index" link.

Regards